# Hypergeometric distribution excercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are 3 red and 4 blue balls in a box. Someone picks two balls from this box randomly. 
What is the probability that if we pick 2 balls from the remaining 5 balls, we pick exactly 2 red.

I calculated the probabilites when we have 1,2 and 3 red balls remaining, then I added these up. Is that correct? I got $P=0,4$ but it seems a lot to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the balls all have ID numbers. Now imagine taking a ball from the box, then another, then another, and so on, until we have taken out all seven. All sequences of balls are equally likely.

The probability the third and fourth balls are red is the same as the probability that the first and second are red, that is, $\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{2}{6}$.

**Remark:** As an exercise, I suggest also doing this problem the harder way. Alicia picks first. Calculate the probabilities $p_0$, $p_1$, $p_2$ that she gets $0$ red, $1$ red, $2$ red.

Beti picks next. Calculate the conditional probabilities $x$, $y$, $z$, she got $2$ given that Alicia $0$ red, $1$ red, $2$ red respectively ($z$ is $0$).

Then our required probability is $p_0x+p_1y+p_2z$. Calculate. After a while, you will get the same number as the one we got using the simple calculation that we used to find the answer.

Comment: Why are those probabilites the same? We don't know how many red and white balls are left in the box.

Comment: The answer gives an argument for why they should be the same. Imagine the balls are labelled. If we pick one ball out at a time (for simplicity do this with all $7$), then all sequences of labels are equally likely. Also, perhaps doing the exercise suggested in the remark at the end will help to persuade you.

Comment: But we pick 2 balls at a time.

Comment: If we are dipping our hand into the bag, and touch one of the balls we will pick up a microsecond later than the other one we will pick, that makes no difference to the probability associated with the "hand" we get.

Comment: You have the correct intuition that the balls Alicia picks influence the probabilities for Beti, who picks later. But with **no knowledge** of what Alicia got, all hands of $2$ for Beti are equally likely. (By hand of $2$ I mean that the balls have ID's.)

Comment: It is weird that we get the same probability as if it didn't matter that someone already picked 2 balls out of the box.

Comment: It takes a while to get used to, then it will seem obvious. It really will help to do the calculation the long way. Let's look at a simpler problem. Alicia removes the balls one at a time. What is the probability the $6$-th ball she removes is red? Is it beginning to be clear that the probability is $\frac{3}{7}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is getting clear.

Comment: I am happy that it is becoming clear.